# Python: Read CSV file and write to another text file

Tags: python, csv

**I have this .csv file ...**

```
    id,first_name,last_name,email,date,opt-in,unique_code
    1,Jimmy,Reyes,jreyes0@macromedia.com,12/29/2016,FALSE,ER45DH
    2,Doris,Wood,dwood1@1und1.de,04/22/2016,,MU34T3
    3,Steven,Miller,smiller2@go.com,07/31/2016,FALSE,G34FGH
    4,Earl,Parker,eparker3@ucoz.com,01-08-17,FALSE,ASY67J
    5,Barbara,Cruz,bcruz4@zdnet.com,12/30/2016,FALSE,NHG67P
```

If the opt-in value is empty, its should print "0". The **last** value in csv should print **first**, and then all the name, value pairs in a specific format,  like shown in the expected output file below.

**My expected output**

```
ER45DH<tab>"id"="1","first_name"="Jimmy","last_name"="Reyes","email"="jreyes0@macromedia.com","date"="12/29/2016","opt-in"="FALSE"
MU34T3<tab>"id"="2","first_name"="Doris","last_name"="Wood","email"="dwood1@1und1.de","date"="04/22/2016,"opt-in"="0"
.......
```

**My code so far ..**

```
import csv

with open('newfilename.csv', 'w') as f2:
    with open('mycsvfile.csv', mode='r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        for i,rows in enumerate(reader):
            if i == 0:
               header = rows 
            else:
                if rows[5] == '':
                   rows[5] = 0;
                pat = rows[0]+'\t'+'''"%s"="%%s",'''*(len(header)-2)+'''"%s"="%%s"‌​\n'''
                print pat
                f2.write(pat % tuple(header[1:]) % tuple(rows[1:]))
    f2.close()
```

This code produces this output

```
1   "first_name"="Jimmy","last_name"="Reyes","email"="jreyes0@macromedia.com","date"="12/29/2016","opt-in"="FALSE","unique_code"="ASD34R"‌​
2   "first_name"="Doris","last_name"="Wood","email"="dwood1@1und1.de","date"="04/22/2016","opt-in"="0","unique_code"="SDS56N"
```

**As you can see column "id" is missing, and I want unque_code at first place.**

I will really appreciate any help/ideas/pointers.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using pandas? It can create a dataframe from a csv file, and from there you can rearrange and fill in collumns as you wish

Comment: Nopes, but just googled it and  found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PANDAS

Comment: haha, that might be useful too (who knows) but I think this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html might serve you better

Comment: it's missing what output you get?

Comment: Yeah, found it, Thanks. Is it easy to learn ? I have this one off task, So not sure if its worth spending couple of hours to learn a new library ???

Comment: Your code looks okay. What is it doing differently to what you expect?

Comment: pandas is quite easy, aside from some weird indexing things (.ix/.iloc/.loc) it behaves very much like and ordinary numpy array (but not quite, because it should load collumn names etc.) But batman seems to know how the csv thing works, so maybe he can help ;)

Comment: @Batman Please see the output above ....

Comment: @Matthias Please see the output above ....

Comment: Well, you are ignoring the first position of the row, that's where the id should be, right? `rows[1:]`

Comment: @Fernando what you suggested produced this  output `Jimmy "first_name"="Jimmy","last_name"="Reyes","email"="jreyes0@macromedia.com","date"="12/29/2016","opt-in"="FALSE","unique_code"="ASD34R"‌​​` Still "id" column is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should process separately the header line, and then correctly process each line. You code could become:

```
with open('newfilename.csv', 'w') as f2:
    with open('mycsvfile.csv', mode='r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        header = next(reader)  # store the headers and advance reader pointer
        for rows in reader:
            if rows[5]=="": rows[5] = "0"  # special processing for 6th field
            # uses last field here
            pat = rows[-1]+'\t'+'''"%s"="%%s",'''*(len(header)-2)+'''"%s"="%%s"‌​\n'''
            # process everything except last field
            fd2.write((pat % tuple(header[:-1])) % tuple(rows[:-1]))
```

No need to load the whole file in memory...

Answer (score 5):

You could just modify the way you enter your list in the file like this:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import csv

with open('newfilename.csv', 'w') as f2:
    with open('mycsvfile.csv', mode='r') as infile:
        reader = list(csv.reader(infile))  # load the whole file as a list
        header = reader[0]  # the first line is your header
        for row in reader[1:]:  # content is all the other lines
            if row[5] == '':
                row[5] = 0
            line = row[-1]+'\t'  # adding the unique code
            for j, e in enumerate(row[:-2]):
                line += '"'+header[j]+'"="'+e+'",'  # adding elements in order
            f2.write(line[:-1]+'\n')  # writing line without last comma
```

I modified a little bit the way you get the header, in order to avoid an unnecessary test for all the lines.

If your file is really big and/or you don't want to load it entirely in memory, you could modify to:

```
...
reader = csv.reader(infile)  # no conversion to list
header = next(reader)  # get first line
for row in reader:  # continue to read one line per loop
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks @BusyAnt, but your solution produced this error `TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Works fine on my computer... What Python version are you using? Make sure you convert the reader into a list, otherwise you can't index (and reverse) it

Comment: My Python Version is 3.6

Comment: Ok... given the `print pat` line, I thought you were using 2.x therefore proposed a 2.7 solution

Comment: Working now .... But your code is placing "id" at the end of each row. Also it is placing the last row at the top. I DO NOT want reverse the order. Please see the expected output above. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @BusyAnt Yes, my file is huge, It has about 50 columns and ~150K rows.

Comment: Then you'll prefer the method with `next` ;) similar to the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43117570/5018771). Just wanted to present both